# First Linux Server Partition Setup: Advice on current setup

Tags: linux, partition

I have ordered a dedicated server which comes with 2 x 4TB drives, I have set them to be in RAID 1. Which means I have a total of 3726 GiB to use.

The default config is:

```
PART swap swap 16G
PART /boot ext3 512M
PART / ext4 2014G
PART /home ext4 all
```

I don't want any complicated partitions, just something which allows me to utilize the whole drive. Is this a good setup or does it need to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

That looks pretty good, if you want to be able to utilize for the the RAID you could put the "/" and "/home" directories in the same partition, but it really depends on what rolls this server will be used for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to evaluate the following:

- Are you *sure* you need to use a bootloader [version] that has trouble reading ext4, but works fine with ext3?
- Is the distribution you are installing clever about kernel updates, or could it run into trouble when that partition is full?
- If some runaway task starts filling up the disk, what is worse: full / or full /home?
- Is there really a reason to have 2 huge partitions (as opposed to one huge and 1-2 small ones)?

You might be better off saying / is fixed 30G and all data is configured to be stored in some other mount, either /home or /database or whatever seems appropriate.